# how to store an integer type value or an object type value into a char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I was trying to store an integer type value and an object type value into a char array. I tried to use cast, but it did not work. the compiler throws a castexception. I wonder if there any method like Integer.parseInt() to convert it.
appreciated for your answer.

Comment: Can you add examples of what you are trying to do? What do you mean by store "object type value into a char array"? What kind of objects are you trying to store?

Comment: To add more informations to your question use [edit] option placed below your question.

Comment: For now we can only post very general answers, which may, but not necessary will help you. To get better answers sooner [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31642860/edit) [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - minimal code example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly your question here is but what I understood is that you want `integer` values to be converted to string and then chop each characters and store them in a `char array`. If that is your requirement then this is how you are going to solve your problem. Regarding `object` type value, you can refer to what Samrat Dutta said.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 145689; // Taking an integer
    String string = Integer.toString(input); //Converting to string
    for(char c: string.toCharArray()) //Putting them inside a character array
    System.out.println(c);  

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**You simply cannot store objects of other classes into a `char` array.** It doesn't work that way. You can only store objects of the same `class` or `subclass` in an array. Or, what you can do to store different objects, including numbers and characters in the same array is to **use an `Object` array, as `Object` is the super class of all other classes in Java.** And then cast your objects into `Object` type, or `autobox` and cast `primitives` to `Object` type and then add them to the array.

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder if he was talking about serialization ie converting an object to a `byte[]`

Comment: ... or simply storing Strings as `char[]`. This question can't be answered properly without more informations from OP. Also as it says now it will not be useful to anyone except OP.

Comment: The question atleast doesnt say anything about serialization or writing to any other file. But you are right. Maybe he is trying to save information into some kind of an array, and then store it somewhere. But then also he will need to store everything as Object type. If he wants to do it in an array.